# Using Import returns "Unexpected token import"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import

I am trying to use ES6 import in my code and it work's fine on my PC, but I just bought a Ubuntu VPS and installed node v8.10.0 and when I try to run the same script, I get an error

```
import { createServer } from "http";
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at createDynamicModule (internal/loader/ModuleRequest.js:52:15)
    at setExecutor (internal/loader/ModuleWrap.js:40:23)
    at file:///root/amv1/server.js:8:36
```

I have `"type": "module",` part in my package.json so I don't really understand why it gives this error.

How can I get my my `node` to recognize `import`?

EDIT: Used the wrong NodeJs version...

Comment: I don't think node v8 supports import statements, do you mean v18?

Comment: ES6 imports are supported natively in node v13+, and you should really use a more up to date version of node, at least v16+

Comment: My bad. I just tried upgrading it with `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -` and then `sudo apt-get install nodejs` and when I try to run node i get an error `nodejs: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by nodejs)
`

Answer (score 0):

Silly question but have you tired:
const createServer = require('http');
?
I might have that syntax incorrect but just wondering if you have tried it.

Comment: Actually it might be more like:
const http = require('http');
let { createServer } = http;
Just a thought.